# Coercion of roots of unities in MAGMA

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, magma-cas

In MAGMA, I want to do computations in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y]$. Say I want to form elements such as $\zeta x$, where $\zeta$ is some root of unity. MAGMA doesn't automatically regard $\zeta$ as an element of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, and so I will need to tell it to do it.
I tried

> P := PolynomialRing(AlgebraicClosure(), 2, "grevlex");
>
> P!RootOfUnity(3);
>
> RootOfUnity(3)*x

but I get

> Runtime error in '!': Illegal coercion
>
> Runtime error in '*': Bad argument types
>
> Argument types given: FldCycElt[FldRat], RngMPolElt

What would be the best way to make this work?

Comment: @MorganRodgers thanks for the comment! It is exactly what I meant to write. But as you note it doesn't really fix the issue. I now reformulated my poorly posed question - it is all about how to make MAGMA accept roots of unities as elements of AlgebraicClosure(). I guess the issue is that AlgebraicClosure() is not really $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ but rather some finite extension. So I guess I would have to somehow arrange that this extension contains the cyclotomic field'

Comment: No, `AlgebraicClosure()` does give you $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/429#4532

Comment: @MorganRodgers I meant 'the system works by automatically constructing larger and larger algebraic extensions of an original base field as needed during a computation, thus giving the illusion of computing in the algebraic closure of the base field.' Thanks for the link! I saw that command, but it didn't work either.. now I abbreviated A:=AlgebraicClosure() and it works.

Comment: `r := RootOfUnity(5,AlgebraicClosure());` works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Q:= Rationals();
    F := AlgebraicClosure(Q);
    P<x,y> := PolynomialRing(F,2);
    zeta:=RootOfUnity(3,F);
    zeta*x+y^2
```

(RootOfUnity(n,F) is implemented for the fields containing one, not for the polynomial rings)